# Take the user to Passcode Settings page from your app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiapplication, iphone-x

Using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` will take the user to app settings, is there any url for taking the user to Passcode or FaceID settings page of Setting app ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's docs, there's only this option to open your app's settings.
If I remember correctly, there used to be a way to open (some) individual settings, but that was several iOS versions ago.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/settings_launch_url